# Can't forget session from ajax request in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, session, laravel-5

I am running a jquery ajax post to my controller, where i check if a session exists. If that is the case i read the value, forget my session and return some data to the view.

If i use session()->has in the controller function after i use forget, it is removed. But when i reload the page and do the ajax request again the session is still there.

In my controller i tried removing it with both forget and pull.

```
$request->session()->forget('last_history_id');
$request->session()->pull('last_history_id')
```

So my question is, why can't i forget sessions in my ajax request so it's gone with the next page reload?

Comment: Where do you set this session value? Maybe reloading the page causes the session variable to be set again.

Comment: That is not the case here, i set the session when a form is posted, then redirect the user to a list where i do my ajax post.

Comment: I suspect you're using the `file` driver for sessions, right?

Comment: Yes that is correct, is there know issues with the file driver?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest changing from `file` driver to `database` driver (or any driver other than file, for that matter) in the `config/session.php` file.

There are some [known issues](https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/8172) when using the `file` and asynchronous calls. I was experiencing the exact issue you have and after switching to `database`, the issue was resolved.

You can switch to `database` rather easily. Here are the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/session) for more help but also relevant code below.

You'll need to setup a table to contain the session items. You may use `php artisan session:table` to generate the migration. Then just `composer dump-autoload`, followed by the `php artisan migrate`. This will create the table in your database for you.

Lastly, just tell Laravel you prefer this driver. Depending on how you've setup your environment, this is either hardcoded in `config/session.php` or pulled from your `.env` file.

Comment: Thanks, it seems to be a combination of file driver and laravel homestead, when deploying to my test server this issue goes away. Will try and update the homestead box and see if it goes away before changing to the database driver.

Comment: @tobros91 Yeah, that's sort of what I gathered from that long GitHub post. For me, the problem was resolved once changing to the database driver but I'm not working in Homestead so perhaps an update of that might help your case. I chased my tail for half a day on this :)

Comment: @tobros91 any updates on this? Did updating or switching to a different driver resolve?

Comment: Updating homestead did not solve my issue. It seemed like laravel could not remove the session when multiple async ajax request where running. I set async false and made sure this specific request always was run when the other request had finished.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is probably associated to mine:

I recently had an issue where the `session_id` was changing when using AJAX requests. It may be that when you check the session, it's actually a new one. So when you forget it, it has no impact on the browsers primary session.

The problem may have been a double-bind of the `web` middleware on a route. I failed to notice that web was already applied in `RouteServiceProvider`. After removing `'middleware' => 'web'` on my problem routes, this issue went away completely.